# Creating an object list and allowing the user to add data

Tags: c#

Hi I am trying to build a contact managers program using an list to store and display the data. I need to view a report that displays a summary of contacts available and then have a menu to allow the user to interact with the program. I need to make a method to allow the user to create a new contact which will contain their first and last name, phone number, email address and type. but I am not sure as to how to do this with an array.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //The MAXPLAYERS constant is the physical table size
        const Int32 MAXCONTACTS = 23;

        //Declare the player tables

        Contact[] contacts = new Contact[MAXCONTACTS];

        //Keep track of the actual number of contacts (i.e. logical table size)
        Int32 contactCount = 0;
        Int32 number = 0;
        String lastName = " ";
        String phoneNumber = " "; 
        String emailAddress = " "; 

        String firstName = " "; ;

        Console.WriteLine("Contact List");
        // display the menu to the user
        Console.WriteLine("Enter option or M for menu:");
        //Main Driver
        char menuItem;
        menuItem = GetMenuItem();
        while (menuItem != 'X')
        {

            ProcessMenuItem(menuItem, firstName, lastName, phoneNumber, emailAddress, contacts, ref contactCount, MAXCONTACTS);
            menuItem = GetMenuItem();

        }
        Console.WriteLine("\nThank you, goodbye");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    static char GetMenuItem()
    {
        char menuItem;
        DisplayMenu();
        menuItem = IOConsole.GetChar((Console.ReadLine()));

        while (menuItem != 'C'
            && menuItem != 'L' && menuItem != 'X' && menuItem != 'R' && menuItem != 'U' && menuItem != 'D')
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nError - Invalid menu item");
            DisplayMenu();
            //menuItem = IOConsole.GetChar((Console.ReadLine()));
        }
        return menuItem;
    }

    static void DisplayMenu()
    {
       Console.WriteLine("C-> Create Contacts");
       Console.WriteLine("R-> Remove Contacts");
       Console.WriteLine("U-> Update Contacts");
       Console.WriteLine("D -> Load data from file");
       Console.WriteLine("S-> Save data to file");
       Console.WriteLine("L-> View sorted by last name");
       Console.WriteLine("F-> View sorted by first name");
       Console.WriteLine("P-> View by partial name search");
       Console.WriteLine("T-> View by contact type");
       Console.WriteLine("Q-> Quit");
    }

    //Routes to the appropriate process routine based on the user menu choice
    static void ProcessMenuItem(Char menuItem, String firstName, String lastName, String phoneNumber,
        String emailAddress, Contact[] contacts, ref Int32 contactCount, Int32 MAXCONTACTS)
    {
        switch (menuItem)
        {
            case 'C':
                createContact();
                break;
            case 'R':
                removeContact();
                break;
            case 'U':
                updateContact();
                break;
            case 'D':
                LoadToFile();
                break;
            case 'S':
                saveToFile();
                break;

            case 'L':
                sortByLastName();
                break;
            case 'F':
                sortByFirstName();
                   break;
            case 'P':

                   break;
            case 'T':

                   break;
            case 'Q':

                   break;

        }                   
    }

     public static void createContact()
    {

    }
```

Here is the enumeration method that is inside my contact object class and is used for the type.

```
enum ContactTypesEnum { Family, Friend, Professional }
```

Comment: For starters, you're using an Array; not an ArrayList. Rather than give you one specific line to replace, here's a basic intro to that - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist(v=vs.110).aspx There are more issues than that in this code though, and to fix them I might need a better idea of what you were intending with it...

Comment: Maximum values? `ArrayList`? Is this 1990?

Answer (score 0):

There are many possible ways to achieve this and one could be declaring an object of type `List` with generic type on it such as `List<T>` where T is the type of an object.

You can declare either a `List<Contact>` or derive a class based on `List<Contact>`.

For further learning I would suggest to check some articles for `List<T>` class.
Reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx

And you can also check the code below as additional learning material:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data;

namespace TestContacts
{
    public enum ContactTypesEnum { 
        Family, 
        Friend, 
        Professional 
    }

    public class Contact
    {

        public int Number { get; set; }
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
        public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public ContactTypesEnum Type { get; set; }
    }


    //I would suggest you check the List collection with generic data types
    //so you will be able to assign your own objects
    public class ContactCollection : List<Contact>
    {
        public Int32 ContactCount
        {
            get
            {
                return this.Count;
            }
        }
    }



    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Contact c1      = new Contact();
            c1.Number       = 1; //Id?
            c1.LastName     = "Doe";
            c1.FirstName    = "John";
            c1.EmailAddress = "johndoe@email.com";
            c1.PhoneNumber  = "12345678";
            c1.Type         = ContactTypesEnum.Friend;

            //Create more contacts...

            //Add all contacts here
            ContactCollection contactList = new ContactCollection();
            contactList.Add(c1);

            //Loop through list
            foreach( Contact c in contactList)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(c.FirstName); //Do something with fields
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `List<T>` instead of Array, as [Joel Legaspi Enriquez](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31644897/2159536) said, you can easily use lots of useful **Linq** functions on a list as an `Enumerable` object by adding `using System.Linq;` at the begging of your program.
I'm sure you can use it by your own. or Google **Linq** in C#! ;)